# Why can't I use the member function to get a member variable when I use <set> iterator?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

```
class Test
{
private:
    int v;

public:
    Test(int h)
    {
        v = h;
    }
    int getV()
    {
        return v;
    }
    bool operator < (const Test& b) const
    {
        return v < b.v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set <Test> st;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Test t(i);
        st.insert(t);
    }

    for(set<Test>::iterator it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << (*it).getV() << endl;
        //Test it2 = *it;
        //cout << it2.getV() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will be

> |error: passing 'const Test' as 'this' argument of 'int Test::getV()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

but if I use `Test it2 = *it; cout << it2.getV() << endl;`, it will work well. Why does it use the words 'const Test' and why the code can't work?

Comment: An unrelated comment: `(*it).getV()` would look better and more idiomatic as `it->getV()`

Answer (score 6):

`std::set` iterators return const references because `set`s are sorted, and if you change the value of an object in a set then it could be in the wrong position for the new value. That could make the object un-findable and worse.

When you do

```
Test it2 = *it;
```

You're making a copy of the object, and you can modify the copy as much as you like. You can't mess up the `set` by modifying the copy.

The problem is that your `getV()` method is not correctly const qualified. It should be:

```
int getV() const
{
    return v;
}
```

And then the first code will compile and work just fine.

Failing to apply const where it's correct will often cause these kinds of problems. You should work to correctly apply const-qualificiations.

Answer (score 1):

A `set` iterator is a const iterator.  You'll need to mark `getV()` as const (which it should be anyway since it doesn't change the object):

```
int getV() const // <--
{
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way is to remove the constness of the object refereed by the iterator. In that case, getV doesn't need to be a const method. Check the modified code below:

```
for(set<Test>::iterator it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++)
{
    cout << (const_cast<Test*>(&(*it)))->getV() << endl;
    //Test it2 = *it;
    //cout << it2.getV() << endl;
}
```

I don't understand why the above answer was down-voted. I just gave an example of doing it another way. In some cases we have to do that. There are times when we need to set some value in the object. Can the down-voters kindly see the reasons looking at the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int v;
    int w;

public:
    Test(int h, int i)
    {
        v = h;
        w = i;
    }
    int getV() const
    {
        return v;
    }
    int getW() const
    {
        return w;
    }

    void setW(int a) // This will not screw up the set as only v is used for comparison
    {
        w = a;
    }

    // Operator < is not using only v for comparison
    // of objects and not using w for that purpose
    bool operator < (const Test& b) const
    {
        return v < b.v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set <Test> st;
    for(int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Test t(i, i);
        st.insert(t);
    }

    for(set<Test>::iterator it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++)
    {
        const_cast<Test*>(&(*it))->setW(1000);
    }


    for(set<Test>::iterator it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->getV() << " " << it->getW() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know that there's reason, why set iterators are const - right?

Comment: `const_cast<>()` is extremely dangerous, and should be avoided at all costs, especially in a case such as is where there are several solutions available that do not break const correctness.

Comment: @Sambuca Many things are dangerous, but can be used judiciously. C is a dangerous language too!!!! const_cast is dangerous, but sometimes we need to use that. Otherwise, that feature wouldn't have been there (Just check how "goto" is used heavily in Linux kernel code, but you will find too many suggestions to avoid the abusible goto). Suppose, you want to access a function setV (via the iterator) which does modify the object? What do you do here?

Comment: @Sambuca if we change the object via the iterator or by some other method, the structure may get screwed up sometime. In this example, suppose you set the private variable v (via setV), this will be a disaster. But then, suppose it had another member w (which is not used by the operator < for comparing with another object), then setting that value won't cause any harm.

Comment: But obviously in this situation it is a problem. The solution is simple, mark the getter as const (which should be done anyway) and you're fine. Not my downvote tho.